# Copying and renaming all files in a directory containing a substring in their names using cmd in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple files under a folder as following:

```
xV7.2.txt 
xV7.3.txt
xV7.4.txt 
yV7.2.txt
yV7.3.txt  
yV7.4.txt
zV7.2.txt
zV7.3.txt
zV7.4.txt
```

I want to be able to copy all the filenames containing the substring `V7.4`, to the same directory, but with new names like so:

```
xV7.5.txt
yV7.5.txt
zV7.5.txt
```

I'm currently trying to do this like this:

```bash
for %%a in (C:\Users\username\Desktop\Batch\*.txt) do (
    findstr "V7.4" "%%a" >nul && (
        xcopy %%a C:\Users\username\Desktop\Batch\result\
    )
)
pause
```

But these lines don't seem to work, they don't even copy the files which contain `V7.4`.

Does someone have any idea about how to do this properly or what I am missing here?

Comment: There was no need to delete your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75685191), then re-ask it. I would have deleted my comment, once you had added some code to ask an on topic question about!

Comment: This kind of attitude is not good at all, I'm new to this site and this is not helping. If you knew the solution you could have just answer the question instead of keep blaming about simple mistakes.

Comment: `findstr` searches for a text string **in a file**. Apply https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html technique to search for a text string **in another string**.

Comment: Maybe this will help you `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s "c:\folder\path" ^| findstr /l "V7.4"') do (........)`

Comment: @zalky, you've been an account holder here for almost 3½ years, hardly what I'd term 'new to this site'. That is plenty of time to have read through the content linked within [ask], have seen that there is an [Edit] button below your question. And please don't try to make me out to be a bad person, when I'd already made improvements to your submission, (which you'd deemed good enough to copy accross to this repost of it). Currently your question make no attempt whatsover to perform the task you laid out. So which specific part of your code do you need us to help you to fix?

Comment: @Compo This site is supposed to be a helper community for developers but instead whenever I post something to get help I come across with toxic people such as you sadly. Me being here for almost 3 years doesn't mean that I use this site for years, people have downside in their lives, not everyone is a nerd like you are and can spend their entire time in this site, you are so clever that you should have thought this already. We are creating a toxic conversation here thanks to your 'big' help, thanks a lot you have done a great job!

Comment: If your filenames are _really_ like the posted ones, then this should work: `copy ?V7.4.txt ?V7.5.txt`